# Bounty expiring soon and completed simultaneously according to the inbox notification?

Tags: support, bug, bounties, notifications, wording

Is it normal according to common logic that "expiring soon" bounty "is completed"?

> [image]

> **bounty *expiring soon***
> Your bounty on question "Post notice should indicate a self-deletion even if the author's account has been deleted" *is completed*. You must award it to an answer within 24 hours.

Comment: It can probably be made more clear that there is a grace period. The bounty period ends, but there is extra time to determine who to award it to.

Comment: @Shadow Please don't roll back edits like that. Without having the text in the post itself it's very hard to find this question via search, and those who can't see images will be very lost.

Comment: @Laurel sorry but it made the post worse, hence the rollback. I stand behind it. (edit summary explains why)

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars can we leave text inside html comment part of the post? Would it be usable for searching purposes?

Comment: No it won't get indexed afaik. @Laurel I thought about a "compromise", which is having both screenshot and text, as done [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387129/strictly-necessary-cookies-text-then-not-grammatically-correct) for example. If you want, this would make the post better without taking out something useful.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars Having both works for me, thanks. (BTW neither alt text nor HTML comments are searchable.)

Comment: @Laurel I believe the alt text is indexed by Google though, so still useful for searching, just not in SE search. :)